# Chamando função Jquery em um controller Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Tenho um arquivo com funções `jquery`, e preciso de algumas funções que estão nele para usar dentro de `controllers` no angular, mas sempre tem erro JS que as funções não estão definidas.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    function alerta(msg){
        if(!$('.pinfo').is(':visible')){
            $('.pinfo').html(msg);
            $('.pinfo').fadeIn( 500 ).delay( 3000 ).fadeOut( 500 );
        }
    }


});
```

Angular

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    modulo
        .controller("CarregaCamposController", CarregaCamposController);

    function CarregaCamposController($scope, $http) {

        var http = $http; //variavel conexão ajax escopo global

        var tab;
        var campos  = [];
        var rows_   = [];
        $scope.rows = [];

        try{
            http
                .get("json.php?action=1")
                .then(function (result) {

                    if (result.status === 200) {
                        var dados = result.data;

                        dados.forEach(function (val, key) {
                            if (key !== 0) {// posição 0 do json sempre é preenchida com o nome da fabrica de relatórios
                                //montagem da tabela de campos para montagem do relatório
                                if (tab === "" || tab !== val.descricao[0]) { // Gera uma linha classificando os campos entre suas tabelas
                                    campos.push({id: val.id[1], desc: val.descricao[1], tab: val.descricao[0], tipot: val.input, ct: "1"});
                                    tab = val.descricao[0];
                                } else {
                                    campos.push({id: val.id[1], desc: val.descricao[1], tab: val.descricao[0], tipot: val.input, ct: "0"});
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        $scope
                            .campos = campos;
                    } else {
                        alert("Erro ao carregar o arquivo JSON!");
                    }
            });

        }catch(e){
            alert("Erro.:"+e);
        }


        $scope
            .doConfirm = function(){

                alerta("teste");

            };

    }

})();
```

ja importei o arquivo com jquery, antes e depois do arquivo do angular, da o mesmo erro, engraçado é q funções nativas do jquery, como mask, fadein, fadeout, eu consigo chamar dentro dos controllers normal.

tentei importar assim

```
import $ from 'funcs.js';

(function () {
    'use strict';

    modulo
        .controller("CarregaCamposController", CarregaCamposController);
```

deu erro

```
The controller with the name 'CarregaCamposController' is not registered.
```

Comment: seu módulo não contém jQuery, importe com `$`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714286/call-jquery-function-from-angularjs-controller

Answer (score 1):

Você tem um problema de visibilidade de escopo de variável (não confunda com `$scope`).

Na sua primeira chamada,

```
$(document).ready(function () { function alerta(msg){/.../}});
```

Você está criando uma função, `alerta()` *dentro do escopo da função de callback* chamada por `ready()`.

Quando você executa o seguinte código:

```
$scope.doConfirm = function(){ alerta("teste"); };
```

Você está tentando chamar uma função chamada `alerta()` que seja visível *a partir daquele escopo*.

Já que a sua função original está escondida dentro aquele escopo de função anônima, você não a está alcançando.

Um teste, *não sugerido como implementação final*, para verificar a visibilidade da função seria adicionar a função ao objeto `window`:

```
$(document).ready(function () { window.alerta = function (msg){/.../}});
```

Assim a função pode ser referenciada no código angular, já que agora o escopo é acessível:

```
$scope.doConfirm = function(){ window.alerta("teste"); };
```

Comment: mano, tu é foda, eu tinha tentado, usar o obj window, q nele te referencia a todas funções JS carregadas, mas sem alterar a função no funcs. tentei só o window.alerta(), mas é engraçado, outras funções funcionaram, mas JS normal, essa que tava no ready() não funcionou

mas vlw muito cara, deu certinho agora, é nós!

Answer (score 0):

Eu só preciso usar as funções que estão dentro do `funcs.js` dentro com meu controller.